# Update uniforms or get data from fragment shader after image processing

Tags: javascript, image-processing, three.js, glsl, webgl

I do some image processing in the fragment shader (thresholding) and I would like to access the result from JavaScript. Then I can save out the modified image using regular JavaScript.

I pass the original texture to be segmented to fragment shader as a uniform, then I do the thresholding. It renders properly on screen. Now I want to access the thresholded image in order to save it out.

I am not even sure that makes sense given the fact that fragment shader runs over pixels rendered of the screen.

I understand most of the constraints and I am wondering in general if there is a good technique to perform some heavy image processing in the fragment shaders and be able to get the processing results out of the shaders somehow.

One other use case I have in mind: flood filling from the mouse cursor, etc.

Javascript is too slow for me and maybe web workers could help but I was hoping to leverage the GPU to do my image processing.

(I am currently using THREEJS + custom shaders - probably not relevant but FYI)

Best,
Nicolas

Comment: You will probably need to look into readPixels which will give you the raw RGBA data, these must then be used to generate the actual image. Due to the performance overhead you might want to consider doing the processing on a separate FBO and once it is done use the FBO on your canvas and to generate the image from it.

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.14.12

Answer (score 1):

There're two ways to solve your problem (if I understood the problem correctly). So, let's say we have a `canvas`. We render our processed image to that canvas. Now we can save the image as a JPEG or PNG blob:

```
canvas.toBlob(
    (blob) => {
        /* do something with the blob, i.e. send it to a server */
    },
    'image/jpeg',
    0.95
);
```

Or as data URL:

```
const imageAsDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
```

Also, if for some reason you want access to actual values of pixels of the image, you can read them via WebGL call (assuming, that `gl` is the context):

```
const pixels = new Uint8Array(4 * canvas.width * canvas.height);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```